# fp-ts - how to reverse curried function order

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, currying, fp-ts

I am using fp-ts and have run into a scenario where I have a curried function comprised of two functions, for example:

```js
const newFunction = (name: string) => (greeting: string) => console.log('Hello ' + name + ' ' + greeting);
```

This is a trivial example but I have certain pipes where it would behoove me if I could reverse the function order and say end up like this:

```js
const newFunction = (greeting: string) => (name: string) => console.log('Hello ' + name + ' ' + greeting);
```

Within fp-ts, is there a way to generate this desired result, I found [this article](https://rlee.dev/practical-guide-to-fp-ts-part-5) outlining the `ap` function but in code this did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flow](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/function.ts.html#flow) instead of [pipe](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/function.ts.html#pipe) if you want to reverse the order of functions.

But if you just want to reverse the order of curried functions, use the [flip](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/function.ts.html#flip) function. e.g:

```js
import { flip } from "fp-ts/function";

const sayHi = (name: string) => (lastName: string) =>
  `Hello, ${name} ${lastName}`;

console.log(sayHi("John")("Doe")); // Result: Hello, John Doe

const reverseSayHi = flip(sayHi);

console.log(reverseSayHi("Doe")("John")); // Result: Hello, John Doe
```